# Select data from table from AJAX request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have AJAX request to select data to table

Here is it

```
<script>
function sender(element) {
    var email = $(element).data('email')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Email: email,
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("SendEmail", "Clients")',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

It works great and send data to back end

Here is my code on back-end

```
 public ActionResult SendEmail(string Email)
    {
        var email_test_variable = Email;
        var questBlock = db.Clients
            .Where(x => x.Email == email_test_variable)
            .Select(x => new
            {


            })
            .ToList();
```

I need to select password related to this email.

Here is database 
[image]

What I need to write in select

Comment: Do you mean `.Select(x => x.Password)`?

Comment: Why the `.ToList()` - surely there is only one `Client` with a particular email address

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Thank's@CamiloTerevinto

Comment: I think it will be better `.ToString()`? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, `.Select(x => x.Password).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Okay, thank's :) @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique email id in Client table and you need to get password of it then you can get it by below piece of code :

```
var password = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Email.equals(email_test_variable)).Select(y => y.Password);
```

It simply returns the password if email id exists in table.